# Show "out of stock" products only for given time

Tags: configuration, stock

Is there a possibility to show "out of stock" product for given  period of time (fe. 3 month) and then not showing it anymore ?

Comment: for all section of  products???or some products?

Comment: For all products @AmitBera

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new module, that

1. Adds a new table with product id and it's out of stock becoming date
2. Fills this table when a product becomes out of stock. Say, you can handle new-order event.
3. Run a cron job one a day and disable old out of stock products.

Comment: Thanks, but wanted to avoid cronjobs and use build-in solutions. But I'm afraid it's not possible. You're right need to do a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can enable and  disable `out of stock in frontend from admin.`
Goto `admin>System>Configuration>Catalog>Inventory>Display Out of Stock Products` make `yes for` this Period and `after that indexing  all index from Index management`(`admin>System>Index Management`).

After expired  `period  again  check  Display Out of Stock Products`  make `No` and indexing again

Comment: this doesn't work for options in configurable products in magento2.